# Launch a call when in background from a notification in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, uilocalnotification

From iOS8, we can show some prompt options in the `UILocalNotification`
[image: UILocalNotification iOS8]

And in my app I have an option to call the police. As I know, launching a call from background is impossible, so what do you suggest ? Can I launch the app then trigger the call ? Or is there any other option ?

Comment: u can launch the app and call

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform operation in background thread  (not suspended) at arriving of a push notification , you need to send "content-available":@"1" in push notification payload . With this you will able to handle when app in background

You can test after implementing this with a breakpoint.
send push notification when app is running but in background .

content-available

Comment: it's a simple scheduled `UILocalNotification`

Comment: You can call a method from background if your app is using location , palying audio ......  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Okay, we can launch a method, but we can't launch the phone application to make a call.

Comment: yes we can't for that user have to open app , you can send a code to server and call police of that area

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a solution:
When declaring a `UIMutableUserNotificationAction`, you should set it's activation mode as `UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground`:

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction1 =[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    notificationAction1.identifier = @"identifier1";
    notificationAction1.title = @"identifier1";
    notificationAction1.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground; //HERE the tip
    notificationAction1.destructive = NO;
    notificationAction1.authenticationRequired = NO;
```

Then in your AppDelegate method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier1"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
}
}
```

That's it!